# Why do we need to prove $e^{u+v} = e^ue^v$?

Tags: exponentiation, education

In [this book I'm using](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071508619) the author seems to feel a need to prove

$e^{u+v} = e^ue^v$

By

$\ln(e^{u+v}) = u + v = \ln(e^u) + \ln(e^v) = \ln(e^u e^v)$

Hence $e^{u+v} = e^u e^v$

But we know from basic algebra that $x^{a+b} = x^ax^b$.

Earlier in the chapter the author says that you should not assume $e^x$ "is an ordinary power of a base *e* with exponent *x*."

This is both a math and pedagogy question then, why does he do that?

So 2 questions really

1. *Do we need to prove* this for such a basic property?
2. If we don't need to, then why does he do it?  Fun?  To make it memorable?  Establish more neural connections?  A case of wildly uncontrolled OCD?

Also I've always taken for granted the property that $x^{a+b} = x^a x^b$.  I take it as an axiom, but I actually don't know where that axiom is listed.

Comment: How is the function $e^x$ defined in the text?

Comment: $e^x$ is defined as the inverse of $ln(x)$ in this text

Comment: @bobobobo: How is $\text{ln}(x)$ defined?

Comment: @bobobobo In that case, we have *no* a priori information about the function $e^x$, and we've got to establish its basic properties from the definition provided.

Comment: @bobobobo: if you take x^{a+b} = x^a x^b as an axiom, you've just shifted the burden of proof elsewhere: now you need to prove that there actually is a function which satisfies this axiom (say when x is a positive real and a, b are reals).  This is not something you can get around with axioms; you need to actually construct this function one way or another.

Comment: @bobobobo: in other words, I think your confusion here is linguistic.  You know there is an operation called exponentiation which satisfies x^{a+b} = x^a x^b, and the author is defining an operation which he calls exponentiation, so you assume it also satisfies x^{a+b} = x^a x^b.  But you can't assume this.  If I call something red, and you call something red, we aren't necessarily talking about the same color.  We have to prove it, e.g. by agreeing on a unit of length and measuring the wavelengths of the appropriate type of light.  Only then can we agree on the meaning of a statement like...

Comment: ..."the apple is red."  Similarly you have to prove that what the author's defining actually agrees with your previous knowledge about exponentiation.  (I tried to make a similar point in a different way in my answer.)

Comment: -1 for asking a question of the form "Why did the author of my book do this?" without **identifying the book in question**.  This makes things unnecessarily difficult and can waste a lot of people's time as they are forced to guess what the text might say.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: If I could I would up-vote your comment twice.

Comment: @Pete At the risk of being identified as a math noob, added it to the question.  Yes I study from a [$10 math book](http://www.amazon.com/Schaums-Outline-Calculus-5th-ed/dp/0071508619/). (Anticipating next comment (with 12 upvotes):  "Get a new book").  I use it because its straight to the point, has lots of exercises,

Comment: @bobobobo: The property that $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$ is usually proven in stages. For $a$ and $b$ positive integers it is proven by induction, using the definition $x^0 = 1$, $x^{n+1} = x^nx$. For arbitrary integers, it is proven using the definition $x^{-n} = \frac{1}{x^n}$ if $n\geq 0$; for rationals, it is proven using the definition $x^{a/b} = y$ where $y^b = x^a$; then for reals, it is proven using the definition as a limit. But you need to prove it from the definition at each point.

Comment: @bobobobo: There's nothing wrong with inexpensive math books.  Here's another one for just the essentials: http://www.amazon.com/Essential-Calculus-Applications-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0486660974/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1295378818&sr=1-1.  Chapter 4 contains a nice development of the logarithmic and exponential functions.

Comment: @bobobobo: there's absolutely nothing wrong with being a "math noob", and of course everyone who knows some advanced mathematics was at one point a beginner.  I removed my downvote and added an upvote since you identified the book.  @Jonas: "There's nothing wrong with inexpensive math books."  No kidding.  I'll complement your observation with: "There's something wrong with expensive math books." (Namely, they're expensive!)

Comment: @bobobobo: By the way, if this is the book you like the best, go for it.  (A very famous mathematician, Gian-Carlo Rota, once wrote a wry essay championing the Schaum's *Outlines* series as being unpretentiously readable and, consequently, including a lot of books that many people at all levels actually do read, rather than display on their shelves and claim to have read.)  But BTW there are plenty of excellent calculus texts *free online*.  You may wish to take a look.

Comment: I upvoted this question. You have a good point. Directly multiplying 2 numbers is easier than computing their logs then adding them then computing its exponential. I once read on the internet that some people are maybe discontinuing use of the exponential function and that the reason for its use was to make slide rules. It seems to me that if you don't think very much and fail to discover the Tom Cook algorithm, you will find that using simple means, multiplying takes square time but exponentiating takes cubic time. However, the exponential function makes its use in study of radioactive decay.

Comment: I think that some jobs want people who have shown that they know how to think because they will be more likely to recognize and catch problems in general. I guess the job uses the fact that the exponential of a sum is the product of the exponentials and they want people who know how to actually prove it and not just blindly apply it. https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/11813/should-we-program-calculus-students-like-the-physicists-seem-to-want-us-to may have some relevance to this question. This question seems to be a special case of it, the question of whether or not we should

Comment: favourably pick students who know how to prove that the exponential of a sum is the product of the exponentials for the job. Also, exp(x) was directly defined to be the function that is its own derivative and assigns 1 to 0. e was defined to be exp(1). I guess that want you to know how to prove that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ exp(x) = $e^x$.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In fact, such a proof *is* often necessary, which is why many authors write the function $e^x$ as $\exp(x)$ until they establish that it's just a "normal" exponent. For instance, if the original definition is given as

$$\exp(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n,$$

then proving that $\exp(x + y) = \exp(x) \exp(y)$ is non-obvious, and certainly necessary.

Comment: This is very true, though defining the exponential function in this way and proceeding from there is slightly masochistic!

Comment: @Noldorin:  why?  It is an excellent intuitive definition from the point of view of differential equations: it's exactly what you get if you use Euler's method to approximate the solution to y' = y with step size 1/n and take n to infinity.  Certainly it's better motivated from first principles than the power series definition, even if the latter is easier to prove things about.

Comment: @Quiaochu: Oh, it's a lovely definition; only, it makes the following proof less trivial than other definitions. :)

Comment: I remember in Analysis I my instructor defined $e^x$ by its Taylor series. It is easy to check with this definition that this function is increasing, $f(1)=e$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$. It follows imediatelly from these three simple properties that this is what we would call $e^x$... I liked that approach.

Answer (score 37):

Mathematicians have a habit of using the same notation to denote many different concepts.  To justify their overloading, they tend to point to similarities between properties of those concepts.  You may think of the exponential as one concept, but it is actually a large family of related concepts:

- The exponentials $x^n$ where $x$ is an element of an arbitrary [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) and $n$ a non-negative integer,
- The exponentials $x^n$ where $x$ is an element of an arbitrary [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) and $n$ an integer,
- The exponentials $x^n$ where $x$ is an element of an arbitrary group and $n$ a rational (which are not guaranteed to exist in general, and are also not guaranteed to be unique in general),
- The exponential $x^n$ where $x$ is an element of a [topological group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group) where $x^n$ for $n$ rational is unique, and $n$ a real number (defined by limits as in Rudin),
- The exponential $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + ... $ where $x$ is an element of a [topological ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ring) containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and the series converges,
- etc.

It is easy to be fooled into thinking that these are all the same concept because they define essentially the same operation on $\mathbb{R}$, but 1) this is not obvious and **requires proof**, and 2) they generalize in different directions, so should be regarded as different in full generality.  Note that the condition for $x^n$ to be defined where $x$ is an element of a topological group and $n$ a real number is quite strong and rarely satisfied.

Note also that your proof using logarithms runs into unnecessary subtleties when $u, v$ are taken to be complex numbers, since in this setting the logarithm is not uniquely defined.  Nevertheless, the exponential law still holds in this setting; it is one of the basic properties that mathematicians point to to justify calling something an exponential in the first place.

In higher mathematics, the exponential further generalizes to:

- The exponential map in [Lie theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Lie_theory),
- The exponential map in [Riemannian geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Riemannian_geometry),
- The exponential map in [category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category),
- etc.

So it is good to keep in mind that "exponential" does not just refer to one thing.

Comment: You've probably lost the reader when talking about group theory and topology - you certainly lost me. Best to stick to the level of the question, in my view.

Comment: @Noldorin:  the question asks for insight into the mind of the author, and I am trying to provide that insight.  If I wrote a book where it was relevant, I would see a strong need to prove the exponential law, and this is my list of reasons why.  Lately I have also begun to notice that similar answers tend to accumulate quickly on questions like this, so I figured it would do some good to give a different perspective, if not for the OP then for anyone else who's wondered the same thing.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I see what you're trying to do, and the motive is good. However, when the reader is not equipped with the knowledge to understand the "higher-level" explanation (as I would guess), then it's just rather pointless. Being at a very high level in mathematics as you surely are, it is naturally very difficult to learn how to put yourself into the student's mind. Most teachers, especially at the college level, *never* learn it, so it's hardly a big criticism. :)

Comment: @Noldorin: this answer was not intended to address the OP's mindset, but the author's.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Answers are for the questioner, not the author. It would be pretty perverse to do anything but that. To give an example from my own field, I could give my grandmother an explanation of the properties of silicon in terms of quantum mechanics and Bloch theory, but I've really just wasted my time. (Sticking to atoms and crystal structure would be much more sensible.)

Comment: @Noldorin: answers are not _just_ for the questioner.  The reason questions stick around after the OP accepts an answer is that questions and answers are supposed to be searchable and preserved for future users, who may have a very different background from the OP but may be wondering the same thing.  This is an enormous difference between the internet and your grandmother's living room.  Like I said, since I figured several other people would be giving answers at the appropriate level, I thought I would try something different.  And if your grandmother asked about the properties of silicon...

Comment: ...on physics.SE, I'm sure the physics.SE community as a whole would appreciate an answer in terms of quantum mechanics and Bloch theory, even if your grandmother would not be able to appreciate it.

Comment: Saying "A,B,C are several concepts in higher mathematics that differ from your usual view of D, so you shouldn't take the properties of D for granted" is not itself an argument in 'higher mathematics' even though it refers to it.

If Qiaochu used technical details of the latest set-theoretic constructions of group exponential functions by ultrafilters, I might agree with you; but since he just refers to the idea as an example I'd say it's at the appropriate level.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I think you're missing the point again I'm afraid. There are people on physics.SE who would appreciate a low-level answer. I agree with your point about answers being for everyone however. I just think they should state that explicitly. i.e. "This answer elaborates on some of the higher-level concepts. See blah, blah, blah... for more direct answers." - or give the simple answer before you launch into the high-level stuff. As I said, I know it's difficult to relate to people at a very different level to you (I have the same problem), but it's worth keeping in mind. :)

Comment: @Noldorin: I can't help but feel like _you're_ missing the point.  The existence of people who would appreciate low-level answers does not say anything about the existence of people who would appreciate high-level answers.  I guessed that several other people would provide simple answers, and they did - three of them.  This question didn't need a fourth one, at least not until the OP clarified what his definitions were.  Meanwhile, the comments in this answer apply regardless of what definition of exponentiation the OP is using.  I don't know why you think I wrote this answer because I have a

Comment: ...problem relating to people at a different mathematical level.  In this answer, I wasn't explicitly trying to.

Comment: @Qiaochu: We'll have to agree to disagree. This may well be a cultural thing, which I can accept.

Comment: I think your answer was excellent. +1

Comment: Something along the lines of this answer is what I expected/wanted to see when I clicked this link. Very informative. +1

Comment: This discussion reminds me of Mordell's review of Lang's book on Diophantine geometry (http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.bams/1183526083) and Lang's later review of Mordell's book on Diophantine equations (http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.bams/1183532391).

Comment: @KCd: Thanks for those links!

Comment: @KCd: I hope Noldorin appreciates how flattering your analogy is.

Comment: Hey guys, bobobobo here.  This is a good answer.  While the specifics currently are beyond what I know, its helpful to receive pointers into those unknown topics, actually.  So thanks for the answer, Q.  Accepted the other answer since its earlier and actually suffices to solve my problem.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: I'm afraid I don't exactly. It seemed to be more sincere than sarcastic though, so I take it kindly, hah!

Comment: @Noldorin:  I think Pete just means that you are Mordell and I am Lang in this analogy, and being compared to Mordell is flattering.  (I wonder if Pete thinks being compared to Lang is flattering.)

Comment: @Qiaochu: Hah, I see. Nice to put it that way round - I'm not familiar enough with either of the mathematicians or their work to know whether one, both, or neither is admirable!

Answer (score 12):

This may seem like a pretty pointless proof, at least on the surface, but I suspect there's some subtlety in the way the author's defined things here. (It may even appear circular at first, considering that the logarithm is often introduced as the inverse of the exponential function. Saying that, it can be derived the other way round, and this can sometimes be enlightening.)

A rigorous proof for integer exponents is very straightforward indeed, and follows simply from the definition of the exponential function (of arbitrary base). For arbitrary exponents, things get slightly more complicated. I present a more complete proof below.

So, let us suppose that the author began by defining the (natural) logarithm function,

$$\ln a = \int_1^a \frac{dx}{x} .$$

We can then prove the addition property of logarithms, $\ln (ab) = \ln a + \ln b$, by considering

$$
\ln (ab) 
= \int_1^{ab} \frac{1}{x} \; dx 
= \int_1^a \frac{1}{x} \; dx \; + \int_a^{ab} \frac{1}{x} \; dx 
=\int_1^{a} \frac{1}{x} \; dx \; + \int_1^{b} \frac{1}{t} \; dt 
= \ln (a) + \ln (b)
$$

(See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Definitions) for reference.)

The exponential function can of course be defined as the inverse of the logarithm, i.e.

$$exp(ln(a)) = a$$

Now, to prove the property of exponentials, $e^{u+v} = e^u e^v$, we start as follows.

$$\text{Let}\ u = \ln a, v = \ln b .$$

Then, using this property of logarithms and the definition of the inverse, consider

$$e^{u+v} = e^{\ln a + \ln b} = e^{\ln (ab)} = ab = e^u e^v .\ \square$$

That should hopefuly be straightforward enough to follow. There are of course other equivalent definitions of $exp$ and $ln$. (You can for example define the Taylor series of $exp$, use the Cauchy product, and then simplify, but that's slightly trickier.)

Comment: It's also quite common to define $ln(x)$ as the integral $\int_1^a \frac{1}{x} \, dx$, which might be the case here.

Comment: @Jon Yes, he did define $ln(x)$ like that previously

Comment: @Jon: Didn't notice that comment, but I was just writing that in my update as you made it. ;)

Comment: @bobobobo: Then this is your answer. It would have been great if you had given that definition of $\ln(x)$ in your question after Isaac in his comment asked for it.

Answer (score 8):

The necessity of a proof depends very much on how each of those things is defined and the domain over which the variables may vary. For example, if $e^x$ is defined by the power series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$, then there is a very real need to prove that $e^{x + y} = e^x e^y$, and the proof is non-trivial. On the other hand, if $e$ is some constant defined elsewhere and $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, then there's essentially nothing to prove.

I would also like to add that the law doesn't hold everywhere. If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices (or endomorphisms of a vector space) that do not commute, then in general $\exp(A + B) \ne \exp(A) \exp(B)$. This fact allows us to study certain non-commutative groups using the tools of analysis and differential geometry — this is the field of study known as Lie theory.

Comment: @ Zhen:"On the other hand, if e is some constant defined elsewhere and x and y are positive integers, then there's essentially nothing to prove." Why is it there is nothing to prove? How do we know that $x^a x^b = x^{a+b}$ in general $\forall x,a,b$? My line of thought is if I can prove that $e^{a_1 + b_1} = e^{a_1}e^{b_1}$ and $(e^{c})^d = e^{cd}$ then I can choose $a_1 = a \log_e(x)$ and $b_1 = b \log_e(x)$ and prove that $x^ax^b = x^{a+b}$. Or you could prove it for natural numbers, extend it to integers, to rationals to reals and to complex. In either case,there is some proof needed right?

Comment: @Sivaram: If $x^a x^b = x^{a+b}$ for any number $x$ and any positive integers $a$ and $b$ essentially by definition of the notation. The only assumption is that multiplication is associative, so in fact, as Qiaochu alludes to, this is true for $x$ in any arbitrary monoid.

Answer (score 7):

One advanced reason for giving a proof is that in some related contexts such a formula breaks down. On the 2-adic numbers, the power series $A(x) = \exp(2x^2 - 2x)$ when expanded out and written in standard form turns out to converge on ${\mathbf Z}_2$, so in particular $A(1)$ is defined. One can prove $A(1)^2 = 1$, but although naively one may expect $A(1) = 1$ by just plugging 1 directly into the original definition I gave for $A(x)$, in fact $A(1) = -1$.  (The point here is that the naive calculation $A(1) = \exp(2 - 2) = \exp(2)\exp(-2) = 1$ is wrong since $\exp(2)$ doesn't make sense 2-adically.)

Answer (score 2):

One definition of $e^x$ is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$. From this definition, it doesn't automatically follow that $e^x e^y = e^{x+y}$.

In fact, it doesn't even follow immediately that $e^x = \displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = (\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n)^x = (e)^x$. What this means is $e^x$ is just a short hand notation for the limit which after some analysis we realize it as $(e)^x$.

By limit arguments, we can now show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now $e^x \times e^y = (1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}) \times (1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!})$.

Now we need to realize that we can rearrange the terms in the series and multiply terms of the two series since both of them converge absolutely.

Hence $e^x \times e^y = (1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}) \times (1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{y^k}{k!}) = 1 + (x+y) + (\frac{x^2 + 2xy + y^2}{2!}) + (\frac{x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3}{3!}) + \cdots$

Now make use of the binomial theorem to get

$$e^{x} e^{y} = e^{x+y}$$

PS: Though I have taken care to make sure the line of thought is right, you need to be careful when writing down the argument as to when you can interchange terms in an infinite series, multiply out two infinite series etc etc.

Comment: _One_ definition of e^x is what you have written.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I prefer to define $e^x$ as $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$ (at least for complex numbers) and then derive all the other formulas like the infinite series etc from this definition.

Comment: yes, but your use of the word "the" is misleading.  The crux of this question is that it is not trivial to show that multiple definitions are equivalent.  Your second argument doesn't work, either; like I mentioned in the comments, you still have to show that this function _exists._