# How to evaluate the following limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{x^x - (x-1)^x}{x^x}$?

Tags: limits

title says everything. How do I evaluate the limit given ?

Comment: Stefano, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @DJC : plotting it in gnuplot :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps try dividing? Then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^x-(x-1)^x}{x^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[1-\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^x\right]=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right].
$$

Notice 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})}.(*)
$$

Try making a substitution like $u=1/x$ to get a situation in which l'Hôpital's rule applies to find this limit. Remember this will also change the value the limit approaches. It should look something like this:
$$
e^{\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u}}=e^{\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{1}{u-1}}.
$$
Apologies for the poor legibility, I hope it at least gets you started.

*Edit: As Sivaram kindly pointed out, you could use the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{x})^x=e^{-1}$ to get the result right off the bat.

Comment: @yunone: $\lim_{x \Rightarrow \infty} (1 - \frac{1}{x})^x$ is the definition of $e^{-1}$

Comment: @Siviram, thanks for that, I wasn't sure how fair it is to use that. I wanted to show how to find that based on the definition that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ is the definition of $e$, but I will edit this fact in as it makes it much clearer.

Comment: @yunone: One of the definitions of $e^x$ is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{x}{n})^n$. So you can use that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1 + \frac{-1}{x})^x$ is $e^{-1}$.

Comment: @Sivaram, Ah, I was unaware of that! Thank you, I have learned something new then.

Comment: ok so the final limit is $1-e^{-1}$.

Comment: @yunone: You might want to look up this thread http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17711/why-do-we-need-to-prove-euv-euev/17857#17857. It has more discussions on the definition of $e^x$ and what the other equivalent definitions of $e^x$ are.

Comment: @Stefano, yes, that is the correct limit. @Sivaram, thanks for the link, I remember when that thread first popped up. I'll take a closer look now.

Comment: You know... the most interesting fact is that now I have no idea why I asked it... :)