# Equational theory of sedenions and beyond

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider a Cayley-Dickson algebra $(X,+,*,0,1)$, that is an algebra generated from the reals by the Cayley-Dickson construction. From complexes to quaternions, we lose commutativity of multiplication, from quaternions to octonions, we lose associativity of multiplication, and from octonions to sedenions we lose alternativity of multiplication. I conjecture that, in a sense, the sedenions are the final stop. More precisely, for any Cayley-Dickson algebra $X$  that is sedenion or beyond, is the equational theory in the signature $(+,*,0,1)$ for $X$ the same as the equational theory of the sedenions?

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1 ...

Comment: Now crossposted at MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347002/

Comment: I believe this question is unsolved. The answer I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641809/what-specific-algebraic-properties-are-broken-at-each-cayley-dickson-stage-beyon/2578566#2578566) cites [this article](https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/cayleydickson-algebras-and-loops-1736-4337-1-101.pdf) which suggests that there might be an infinite sequence of identities of a certain type that are lost at each doubling step. However, [this other article](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/AGB-100105036) seems to imply that no such identity exists for $n=5$.