# What comes in the next several K-D steps after the sedenions, and what is lost?

Tags: hypercomplex-numbers, sedenions

Wikipedia and elsewhere seem to say that one can keep on extrapolating forever in hypercomplexification, but that you progressively lose operation-equative symetries or whatever you call, e.g. commutativity, associativity, power-associativity, flexibility, etc.

My question is how to determine what is lost next, and next after that, algorithmically. Also, if the post-sedenions have any specific names, for at least the next stage or two.

I don't know what to search on, as I only became sure I was\am mathematically mature yesterday (literally :f  )

Comment: My bad... long day:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641809/what-specific-algebraic-properties-are-broken-at-each-cayley-dickson-stage-beyon