# Is division by a null sedenion a valid operation?

Tags: divisibility, sedenions

So [octonion set provides the largest normed division algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3557638/85628), and starting with sedenions, Cayley-Dickson construction provides algebras with zero divisors.

From what I understand, it means there are pairs of non-null sedenion $(s_a,s_b)$ for which $ s_a·s_b = s_0$ is correct – where $s_0$ stands for the null sedenion $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$. But maybe I already misunderstood something here?

But given that higher order algebra gradually lose algebraic properties as the scale of dimension is climbed, are they any pair of non-null sedenion $(s_c, s_d)$ for which $s_c/s_0=s_d$ holds? That is, is it valid, at least in some cases, to divide by the null sedenion?

Comment: As long as "$a/b=c$" is shorthand for "$a=c\cdot b$" (order mattering here), the answer is clearly negative: just prove directly that $s_0\cdot t=t\cdot s_0=s_0$ for any sedenion $t$. (And if that's not what you mean by "$a/b=c$," what *do* you mean?)

Comment: On a side note, [wheels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory) define a  type of algebra where zero division is somehow possible, although the definition of division and behavior or its operators in general is somehow changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. In the Sedenion algebra you have not only one couple but many such that their product is 0, and 0 is still absorbant for the original product. So you cannot "divide" by 0 because there is no exclusivity.

Comment: Is there infinitely many couples whose product is null?

Comment: Also, is it "there is not a single solution" like for $x^2=k | k \lt 0$ in complexes or is it a different case, and not only because there are possibly infinitely many solutions?

Comment: It is more like "there is no unique factorization" in some rings.