# Is there infinitely many "complex units"

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

As we know, $i$ = $\sqrt{-1}$, a simple complex unit. In complex space of two dimensions, you graph an axis of $a+bi$ where $i$ is your second dimension axis.

Now, you also know, in three and four dimensional space, you use the quaternions, such that $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$. Then, in three dimensional complex space, you can have it in form $a+bi+cj$.

Yet, are there "hexternions" such that $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = l^2 = m^2 = ijklm=-1$

And also, are there k-ternions such that $t_1^2 = t_2^2 = ... = t_k^2 = t_1 t_2 ... t_k = -1$? And you can have any finite amount of dimensions in complex space?

Comment: Any element of the form $\;\zeta_n:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ is a unit in the complex field in the sense that $\;\zeta_n^n=1\;$ ...

Comment: The answer depends a bit on what properties you want your creations to have - whether you want to be able to multiply them as well as add them, for example. You might be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionAlgebra.html (Cayley Numbers  and Octonions are two names for the same thing)

Comment: Given what I need, I need to be able to multiply and add them; not much else. The fact of the matter is I need some kind of way to know how to have complex units for finitely dimensional complex space.

Edit: That is, space of form $a+bi+ci_2+di_3+...+zi_k$

Comment: Sum them? Then I think you may want to talk about complex *algebras*, not merely complex vector spaces...

Comment: Summing them such that the sum can be graphed on a "complex space"

Comment: I've no the slightest idea what you can possibly mean by that, @someuser ...

Comment: So, you know how you can graph numbers of form $a+bi$ right... What I need is a way to graph numbers of form $a+bi+ci_2+di_3+...$ as somewhat of an "expansion" of $a+bi$. (where $i_k$ for any natural $k$ is complex)

Comment: Is this even possible? @DonAntonio

Comment: Have you looked up the references I suggested? There is also a paper here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105155 which is a bit less basic, but has some good discussion in between some of the more advanced mathematics.

Comment: @someuser, perhaps you're thinking of Hamilton's Quaternions, a $\;4$-dimensional real algebra?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes.

Comment: Also, how they can be expanded to any $2^k$-dimensional real algebra consisting of $2^k$ complex units.

Comment: Look up the Cayley-Dickson construction.

Comment: Not if you want to keep some characteristics, @someuser. For example, the only **division** real algebras (i.e., whithout non-zero zero divisors) are $\;\Bbb R\;,\;\;\Bbb C\;,\;\;\Bbb H\;$ . If you're willing to give up associativity (hello!) you also have the octonions $\;\mathcal O\;$ , etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually they come as **R** $^{2^k}$, where, for $k=0$ we have the real numbers **R**, for $k=1$ we have the complex numbers **C**, for $k=2$ we have the [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) **H**, for $k=3$ we have the [octonions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) **O**, for $k=4$ we have the [sedenions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion) **S**, etc. See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86434/what-lies-beyond-the-sedenions), as well as the articles on:

- [hypercomplex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number), [bicomplex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number), [multicomplex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicomplex_number),
- [biquaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biquaternion), [split-quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion), [split-biquaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-biquaternion), [dual quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion), [dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number),
- [Musean hypernumbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musean_hypernumber) $\big($conic quaternions/octonions/sedenions$\big)$, [hyperbolic quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_quaternion),
- [Clifford algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra), [Cayley-Dickson constructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Dickson_construction), [Pauli matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can build tessarines with any number of dimensions of the form $2^n$, and they still will be commutative and associative.