# Is multiplication not just repeated addition?

Tags: arithmetic

If multiplication is not repeated addition, what is it? How do you define multiplication?

All of us had to memorize the multiplication table in elementary school, but how did they come up with it if so many people claim that it is wrong to think of it as repeated addition?

Voodoo magic?

Comment: Who claims that it's wrong to think of it as repeated addition?

Comment: "There are differences amongst educationalists as to which number should normally be considered as the number of copies and whether multiplication should even be introduced as repeated addition." - Wikipedia

Comment: Whether it's wrong to think of it as something or whether that's the best way to introduce it to children are two quite separate questions. As to which number should be considered the number of copies, that doesn't make any sense since multiplication is commutative.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is... If 3 times 0.3 is the same as $0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3$, what is 3 0.3 times? How to think about it?

Especially when we have 0.3 * 0.2, This is basically a fraction multiplied with a fraction... But how to interpret the operation of multiplication here? As scaling? Between 0 and 1 it could be thought as division... Am I making any sense?

I am just quite confused.

Comment: It's not just repeated addition, but repeated addition is a very good starting point to define/understand multiplication.

Comment: Okay, I can accept that. So, where do we go from that point? Sometimes multiplication of integers and rationals, to me, differs like quantum mechanics and relativity.

Comment: Keith Devlin has written a few columns at the MAA site in recent years explaining why he thinks it's a bad idea to introduce multiplication to children as repeated addition. See http://www.maa.org/devlin/devlin_01_11.html and the other essays cited there.

Comment: At least for nonnegative integers and rational numbers, you can think of multiplication as meaning "of".  What's $1/2$ of $3/5$?  A child can draw a picture of a cake to figure that out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: the link in your [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64488/if-multiplication-is-not-repeated-addition/64514#comment151833_64488) gives "Page not found". Would you give a new link; am interested in this.

Comment: @Anupam, http://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_01_11.html seems to work now.

Comment: I would argue if you're a kid it doesn't matter how the basic mathematical operations are "introduced". Eg, we're all told that addition is just "combining", and that works. We do not need to think of addition as the successor function repeated n times to do homework or add money together, we're forced to accept that the addition of 1 is just counting and that completely works.

Comment: @Imn32 We all learn from particular. And particular prevents us from understanding generic. But it *completely works* if you only stay with the particular.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The first thing you should consider is that there are, in some sense, different "hierarchies" of numbers. At each stage, we enlarge the class of numbers, and try to do so in a way that leaves everything we could do before still the same, but that now we can do more.

A common way of doing this is to start with the **natural numbers** (sometimes called "counting numbers" or positive integers). We start with $1$, $2$, $3,\ldots$.

Here, we *do* define multiplication as repeated addition. For example, one way to *define* multiplication is to assume we know how to add, and then define it by saying:
$$\begin{align*}
n\times 1 &= n\\
n\times (k+1) &= (n\times k) + n % need to edit at least 6 characters
\end{align*}$$
Using [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), we can show this defines multiplication for *all* positive integers, and that it has the usual properties we know (commutative, so that $n\times k = k\times n$ for all positive integer $n$ and $k$, distributes over the sum, is associative, etc).

Then we have two choices for "expanding our universe of numbers": we can now define negative integers, by considering things that would help us solve all equations of the form $a+x=b$ with $a$ and $b$ positive integers; or we can introduce positive rationals (fractions) by considering all things that would help us solve all equations of the form $ax = b$. Let's do the latter, since that came first historically.

So, we had the positive integers, and we knew how to add and multiply them. Now we are going to have *more* numbers: now, for every pair of positive integers $a$ and $b$, we will have a number "$\frac{a}{b}$", which is a number that satisfies the property that
$$b\times\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = a.$$
We also say that $\frac{a}{b}$ is "the same fraction" as $\frac{c}{d}$ if and only if $ad=bc$ (here we are comparing products of positive integers, so that's fine).

We also notice that our old positive integers can also be considered fractions: the positive integer $a$ is a solution to $1x = a$, so $a$ corresponds to the fraction $\frac{a}{1}$.

Now, how do we add two of these numbers? Since $\frac{a}{b}$ represents the solution to $bx=a$, and $\frac{r}{s}$ represents the solution to $sx=r$, then $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{r}{s}$ represents the solution to *something*; to what? A bit of algebra will tell you that it is the solution to precisely $(bs)x = (as+br)$. So we **define**
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{r}{s} = \frac{as+br}{bs}.$$
There's a bit of work that needs to be done to ensure that if you write the fractions differently, the answer comes out the same (if $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}$, and if $\frac{t}{u}=\frac{r}{s}$, does $\frac{cu+td}{du} = \frac{as+br}{bs}$? Yes). And we also notice that if we add positive integers *as if they were fractions*, we get the same answer we did before:
$$\frac{a}{1} + \frac{c}{1} = \frac{a1+c1}{1} = \frac{a+c}{1}.$$
That's good; it means we are *enlarging* our universe, not changing it.

How about products? If $\frac{a}{b}$ represents the solution to $bx=a$, and $\frac{r}{s}$ represents the solution to $sy=r$, their product will be the solution to $(bs)z = ar$. So we **define**
$$\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{r}{s} = \frac{ar}{bs}.$$
And then we notice that it *extends* the definition of multiplication for integers, since $\frac{a}{1}\times\frac{b}{1} = \frac{a\times b}{1}$.  And we check to see that multiplication and addition still have the properties we want (commutativity, associativity, etc).

(There are other ways to figure out what multiplication of fractions "should be", on the basis of what we want it to do. For example, we want multiplication to extend multiplication of integers, so $\frac{a}{1}\times\frac{b}{1}$ should be $\frac{ab}{1}$; and we want it to distribute over the sum, so we want
$$\frac{a}{1} = \frac{a}{1}\times \frac{1}{1} = \frac{a}{1}\times\left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{b}+\cdots+\frac{1}{b}}_{b\text{ summands}}\right) = \underbrace{\left(\frac{a}{1}\times\frac{1}{b}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{a}{1}\times\frac{1}{b}\right)}_{b\text{ summands}}.$$
So $\frac{a}{1}\times \frac{1}{b}$ should be a fraction which, when added to itself $b$ times, equals $a$; that is, a solution to $bx=a$; that is, $\frac{a}{b}$. And so on).

Then we move on from the positive rationals (fractions) to the positive reals. This is more complicated, as it involves "filling in gaps" between rationals. It is very technical. But what it turns out is that for every real number you can find a sequence of rationals $q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots$ that get progressively closer to each other and to $r$ (we say the sequence "converges to $r$"); it won't hurt too much if you think of the $q_i$ as being progressive decimal approximations to $r$ (they don't have to be, and ahead of time you don't have any notion of decimal approximation, but you can think of it that way for our purpose). So then the way we define multiplication of real numbers $r$ and $s$ is to find a sequence of rationals $q_1,q_2,q_3,\ldots$ giving the approximation to $r$, and one $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots$ giving the approximation to $s$, and we define $r\times s$ to be whatever it is that the sequence
$$p_1\times q_1,\ p_2\times q_2,\ p_3\times q_3,\ \ldots$$
approximates. This ensures that if you take *rational numbers* and multiply them as if they were reals you get the same thing as if you multiply them as rationals, and likewise for integers.

So multiplication of positive reals is really a series of approximations made up by multiplying rationals; and multiplication of rationals is really a way to codify solutions to certain equations with integers; and it is only multiplication of (positive) integers that really corresponds to "repeated addition".

Finally, once you have the positive reals, you can introduce the negative real numbers. We consider solutions to equations of the form $a+x=b$ with $a$ and $b$ positive real numbers. Some of these already have solutions, some don't. This gives us "zero" and "negative reals". We then extend the definition of multiplication to "zero" and to "the negative reals" in a way that makes sense relative to this definition. Turns out we need to make $0\times r = 0$ for all $r$, and have to respect the "rules of signs" to make sure everything still works. So we define it that way to make sure everything works and what we had before still works exactly the same.

Comment: I enjoyed your answer, thank you!

Comment: So, would this be the derivation of the distributive property then?

$n(a+b)=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a+b= \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a + \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b = na + nb$?

If we consider all the variables as positive integers to simplify the derivation, of course.

Comment: @Curiosity: in the interest of avoiding ambiguity, you should have written $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (a+b)$. The parentheses matter here.

Comment: Oh, yeah, indeed. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Curiosity: The properties of addition and multiplication for positive integers usually need to be proven by induction in one way or another, if you want to really do it from scratch. Above, you require generalized commutativity and generalized associativity to justify the step from $\sum(a+b)$ to $(\sum a)+(\sum b)$, and you would need to prove several things beyond the definition of multiplication I give to establish the *first* step. Assuming you had all those results in hand, then that would work, but one has to be careful not have a circular argument.

Comment: @Doug: The difference is that the number of times addition is done implicitly in multiplication (according to the interpretation on the table here) is indefinite, whereas an addition table shows the results of adding exactly two numbers together. The fact that addition between two numbers is done in each step of the process - and that addition tables exhaust the minimal examples of addition - are not inconsistent with the fact that they are used in a broader scheme. If you put code inside a FOR loop while programming it doesn't mean you altered the original snippet of code.

Comment: @Doug: Since he explicitly distinguishes between the original axiomatic framework (where you can't define recursion, or use the essence of "FOR loops") and the outside meta-schema (where we actually understand repeated iteration), it's clear he's pointing out that an indefinite number of operations makes a function ill-defined in the former while not the latter. There's obviously an issue of whether distinguishing hierarchies and teaching rigid formalism is healthy / useful pedagogically at an elementary level, but saying repeated operations can't ultimately be understood is just absurd.

Comment: I simply fail to see how repeated operations in the context of multiplication on natural numbers ultimately can get understood.  It's *not* absurd, because no matter how many repeated operations on the natural numbers you understand, there always exists infinitely more that you haven't thought about and simply won't think about.

Comment: I doubt anyone could have given a better answer to this question. Bravo!

Comment: @Doug: Indeed, human beings can't mentally visualize more than say 6 or 7 copies of an object simultaneously, but that doesn't mean, for example, the very concept of whole number addition isn't understood, and understood for arbitrarily large numbers, so your point is patently *disingenuous*. Moreover, the idea that repeated operations cannot be understood *is* utterly absurd, because we would then not have product ($\prod$) and summation ($\sum$) notation and it would throw out a large plurality of all of mathematics. You wouldn't have a computer if not for well-defined repeated operations.

Comment: @Doug: I specifically said the "*concept* of addition," not collectively every possible pattern that can be built from it. Once again you (purposely?) go straight for the least plausible, most illogical interpretation of others' statements - the more you send me the subtle message of "I will warp your intentions as far as I can," the less inclined I am to talk to you. And indeed, whole number addition can be *abstracted* from counting via a comprehension of its general structure so that infinite brain capacity is not required. Saying counting isn't quantitative but qualitative is hilarious.

Comment: @Doug: I'm astounded you're not aware of what the common understanding of basic [addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition) is - this gradeschool concept of number is based on [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality). You don't even need to know about the much higher concept of prime numbers to understand what it means to join collections of objects together. Note further that counting is literally the most prototypical way of measuring quantity (multitude) there is, so is by definition quantitative. BTW, you never answered my previous Q: are you a non-native speaker?

Comment: @anon: He's a [philosophy graduate](http://www.blogger.com/profile/05744695881930867875). Whether that counts as a "non-native speaker", well...

Comment: Arturo: Heh. Sorry for the pings. @Doug: I said "addition can be abstracted from [<---!] counting," from which you should have logically deduced I'm considering counting in a sense that is naturally understood before its abstraction is (i.e. counting of objects). Recall what I said (in the now-deleted thread) about mulling over possible meanings another could have meant by a statement, and reasoning about which are most plausible. Moreover, even counting in the abstract world is working with numbers and so is decidedly "related to" (dictionary definition) quantity, hence is still quantitative.

Comment: Are you presuming that the fraction $\dfrac{a}{b}$ is a solution of $a=bx$? If this is the case then you don't need to quote the definition "_$\dfrac{a}{b}$ is "the same fraction" as $\dfrac{c}{d}$ if and only if ad=bc_". [Because $a=1a$ and $a=\frac{a}{a}a$ implies $\frac{a}{a}=1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705286/equality-of-positive-rational-numbers). It appears you are also presuming that commutative and associative laws hold for rationals. Do you?

Answer (score 9):

At Willie Wong's suggestion, I post my comment as an answer.

Keith Devlin has written a few columns at the MAA site in recent years explaining why he thinks it's a bad idea to introduce multiplication to children as repeated addition. See [this](http://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_01_11.html) and the other essays cited there.

Comment: Oh, man. I totally disagree with this but I'll see what he has to say.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication of positive integers *is* defined as repeated addition. However, this doesn't help us define multiplication by a negative number, or a rational, or anything else -- you can't add three to itself minus four times, or half of a time.  This means we have to start from whole-number multiplication and then "fill in the gaps" to define multiplication for larger classes of numbers.

Comment: How did we fill the gaps? That's my question, exactly. It's quite confusing for me.

Comment: @Curiosity: Something like this: If $n \cdot x$ is $x + \dots + x$ ($n$ times) for $n$ a positive integer, then one declares $(-n) \cdot x$ to be $-(n \cdot x)$, and $(n/m)\cdot x$ to be $(n \cdot x)/m$. And so on...

Comment: No, it's not, even if you exclude 0 from the natural numbers.  Consider (2*1).  There doesn't exist the sum of just one number 2.  Maybe you think you can say "well, that's just the sum of 1 and 1".  But, see, multiplication commutes, so the other way should also work if "multiplication is repeated addition".  Also, if "multiplication is repeated addition", what does (1*1)?  I simply have no idea how to perform an addition with just one element.  (0*0), (0*1), and (0*x) seem even worse.

Comment: @Doug why do you claim that 'there doesn't exist the sum of just one number 2'?  I think when you tell people that a.b is calculated (for naturals) by 'taking a copies of b and adding them all together', they'll know exactly what to do when a is 1, and I don't think the notion is nearly so confusing (even for children) as you're making it out to be.

Comment: @Steven Taking "a" copies of "b" if "a" is less than two, and "a" is a natural number is a contradiction in terms.  By saying "copies" you've indicated a plural while "one" indicates a singular ("zero" indicates *absence*).  So, if we actually could have "one copies" we would one object *and* more than one object at the same time.  That would be a contradiction.  I claim we don't have the sum of just one number 2, because the basic notion of addition is that of a *binary* operation.  If it were not, people would freely write +1, and x+yz, and freely say "the sum of 1."

Comment: @Steven And multiplication also qualifies as a basic operation, due to the way it gets written when it actually gets expressed.

Comment: Doug, so far as I can tell your objections are rooted exclusively in the minutia of English grammar.  The distinction between singular and plural is linguistic, not conceptual.  At any rate, replacing "sum" with "total" and "copy" with "instance" seems to dismiss any issues you raise.

Comment: @user3296 The difference between singular and plural is NOT merely linguistic.  It does qualify as conceptual.  Have you ever heard of the philosophical problem of "the one and the many"?  On top of this, see information on "subitizng".  And no, that won't dismiss the issue here.  The author indicates the context as one where we have multiplication tables.  The table indicates a rule which takes two elements and returns a single element.  In other terms, it indicates a binary function.  So, by the very construction of a multiplication table, you have multiplication as a binary operation.

Comment: @Doug: You take people too literally. Obviously what user3296 wants is to be able to speak of a number of instances without an assumption about singular (1), plural (1+), or even a presence at all (0) (in other words, "a number" - which is the full concept), but the English language doesn't have a graceful way to do this, so people *generally* have become accustomed to understanding phrases such as "$n$ apples" to allow singular or empty cases depending on context, seeing as how often that is the intention behind the utterance, despite the literal grammar indicating otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I gave a long response to this question as part of an answer to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56663/is-there-a-natural-way-to-extend-repeated-exponentiation-beyond-integers/56710#56710). The basic point I want to get across is that repeated addition does not generalize in the way that multiplication generalizes; for example you'd be hard-pressed to think of multiplication of complex numbers or matrices as repeated addition. That is because what they really are are *compositions of functions.*

In particular, multiplication of real numbers is (in my opinion) better thought of as compositions of scalings of the real line. This generalizes immediately to multiplication of complex numbers, which are compositions of scalings-and-rotations of the plane.

(Another point I want to get across is that it is completely unnecessary, even when dealing with natural numbers, to define multiplication as repeated addition.)

Comment: On the other hand, repeated addition does generalize to the hierarchy multiplication -> exponentiation -> tetration -> ....

Comment: @Charles: as I explain in detail in the other question, I disagree that this is a good way to think about either multiplication or exponentiation.

Comment: There aren't really many other options on tetration, though, which was my point.

Answer (score 2):

I like to look at the original geometrical sources: A non-negative number is the length of a line segment, the sum of two numbers is the combined lengths of the segments, and the product is the area of the rectangle with the segments as the sides. I know this has its problems (it's surprisingly hard to get the integers from the reals), but I like to look at things from different points of view.

Comment: When you consider such a perspective, you can always console yourself that the ancient Greeks considered numbers from that point-of-view.  Euclid's number theory existed in that sort of context, including his proofs.

Comment: Additionally, the Archimedean property stated as definition 4 of Euclid's book V is originally due not to Archimedes but to Eudoxus. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudoxus_of_Cnidus

Answer (score 2):

To understand multiplication, discover it yourself (see 2nd section below)!

Starting point: The natural numbers $\mathbb N$ with only one binary operation called addition.

Before long, you'll find it both useful and convenient to define multiplication. For example, you store many cans of Campbell's soup in your ultra-organized pantry.

[image]

You see that two cans are in the front and you have three rows. Without the use of a calculator, you 'know' that you have six cans. You like this so much that you set up a notation for what it means to multiply two natural numbers $a$ and $b$:

${\displaystyle a\times b=\underbrace {b+\cdots +b} _\text{a-times}}$

You call the 'thing being multiplied', $b$, the multiplicand, and the other 'thing', $a$, the multiplier. You are not bothered at all if either $a$ or $b$ is equal to $0$ - you see the result as a big fat zero (no soup).

You like to think about things in an abstract way, and you discover something that 'knocks your socks off' -  multiplication distributes over addition:

$\tag 1 a \times (b + c) = (a \times b) + (a \times c)$

You now think that perhaps multiplication can be viewed as a binary operation in its own right. You then ask if the distributivity law 'gives you back' multiplication as a uniquely defined arithmetic operation. You decide to add the 'law', $\, 1 \times 1 = 1$, and testing some more,

$\quad 2 \times 2 = 2 \times (1 + 1) = $
$\qquad 2 \times 1 + 2 \times 1 = $
$\qquad (1 + 1) \times 1 + (1 + 1) \times 1 =$
$\qquad 1 \times 1 + 1 \times 1 + 1 \times 1 + 1\times 1 = $
$\qquad 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4$

This is a great start! You realize that for your 'laws of arithmetic' it will be both convenient and useful to include multiplication, an operation that is 'tied to the hip' with addition via (1).

---

The link

[What Exactly is Multiplication? \ Keith Devlin](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_01_11.html)

that Gerry Myerson provides contains the quote

*multiplication is complex and multi-faceted*

and the author suggests that to understand multiplication, you need to form a personal 'mental amalgam' with a heuristic, like 'multiplication is scaling'.

Answer (score 1):

Devlin is profane - do not trust him!

Multiplication is repeated addition ($N = n·u= u+u+u+...$, unit is preserved) , but there is another thing called product.($u×u = u^2$, unit is changed).

Euclid had problems with this issue too, but clearly he was aware of it.
Euclid speaks of product $A\times B$ as plane number, and of product $ A \times B \times C$ as solid number.

René Descartes resolved the issue completely.

These terms is often(almost always) misused, because $|A × B| = |A| · |B|$.

Answer (score 0):

Hermann Hankel and George Peacock raised some theory called "The Principle of Permanence of Equivalent Forms", or just the "The Principle of Permanence".

Below are some quote from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086020300628):

> An explicit formulation of the principle of permanence appears in
> George Peacock's 1833 “Report on the recent progress and present state
> of certain branches of analysis”, where it is expressed in the
> following way: “Whatever form is algebraically equivalent to another
> when expressed in general symbols, must continue to be equivalent,
> whatever those symbols denote.” This “Principle of Permanence of
> Equivalent Forms”, as Peacock called it, also stipulates the
> following: “Whatever equivalent form is discoverable in arithmetical
> algebra considered as the science of suggestion, when the symbols are
> general in their form, though specific in their value, will continue
> to be an equivalent form when the symbols are general in their nature
> as well as in their form.”2 For example, if m, n and a denote any
> integers, as they do in what Peacock called arithmetical algebra, then
> it is the case that `ma + na = (m+n)a`. Arithmetically equivalent
> forms like this one are said to have a “necessary” existence (Peacock,
> 1833, 199), for they are true in virtue of the definitions of the
> basic operations (like addition and multiplication). Permanence
> demands that `ma + na = (m+n)a` remains an equivalent form in what
> Peacock called symbolic algebra, where `m`, `n` and `a` may denote anything
> whatsoever.

So, based on the above theory, the result and laws we obtained from the experience of counting, should still hold true in other symbolic scenarios.

---

As to multiplication, both addition and multiplication are just some operations that map two elements to one element. I think you can define any operations on a set to be addition or multiplication. As long as the operations respect the laws you get from arithmetic because of the "Principle of Permanence". The `x` and `+` are just two **symbols** to represent some operations.

When we do multiplicaton for natural numbers, we need to remember all the results of combinations of 1~9. That's all we need to remember to carry out multiplication in decimal system. If you change a system, you may need to remember a totally different set of results.

Answer (score 0):

Kronecker once declared that “Natural numbers were created by God, everything else is the work of men” - the point being that all else is constructed so that it 'fits'.

Addition follows naturally from combining sets, and then it isn't hard to see that you can take part of a set away, which gives you subtraction. But how do you take more away than there is? So we invented negative numbers because it made it possible to subtract a larger number from a smaller.

And multiplication starts naturally with repeated addition, of course, but then you observe that if you have a set consisting of a whole number of smaller sets, you can also go the other way - but that gives you the problem that you can't always do this; thus we invented the rational numbers. And so on. The rules for multiplication of rational numbers, distributive laws etc are invented to make everything work nicely.

The real and complex numbers are 'merely' thinking this through and refining the concepts in the extreme.

This can be summed up as 'algebraic convenience': all operations 'want' to have an inverse, and we end up with groups theory, ring theory etc., and in the end something like the category theoretical definition of [the product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) for multiplication and [the coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) being addition, after which there isn't much hope left.