# Cardinality of $S=\{A,B\}$ where $A=B=\{1,2,3\}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Given a set $S = \{A,B\}$ such that $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3\}$, what is the cardinality of S?

I know this may seem very trivial, and I am inclined to believe that the answer is $2$; my question comes from the fact that $A = B$. Since both $A$ and $B$ are the same, would that not be the same as having a repeated element, therefore making the answer $1$?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934378/why-cant-a-set-have-two-elements-of-the-same-value)

Answer (score 2):

$S$ has one element, so has cardinality $1$.  (Although we have two labels for $\{1,2,3\}$, there is still only one such set.)  Sets don't have duplicates.  ([Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) can have duplicates.  If $S$ were a multiset, it would have cardinality $2$.)  The set $\{x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x\}$ has one element, $x$.

Comment: Well, no. If $A$ $=$ $B$ then the cardinality is truly $1$.

Comment: @SincerelyPrime : D'oh.  Totally did not look at the contents of $A$ and $B$.  <hangs head>

Comment: Haha, happens to the best of us. Often times, I look way too much into a question or problem.

Comment: removed my minus 1, good edit.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of your the set $S$ would be $1$. Since $A$=$B$, the cardinality is $1$.

Also, sets that are subsets of a set are just *items* if you will, and can be counted as elements. The only reason the cardinality is **not** $2$ is because the sets are equal

Comment: The word ''subset'' here has a different meaning, right?

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification!

Comment: If $S=\{1, 2, 3\}$, then $2$ is an element of $S$, which is denoted by $2 \in S$. $S$ is a subset of $S$, which is denoted by $S \subset S$.

Comment: I coincide with you, @user529760. That $x\in A$ for some set $A$ does *not* mean that $s\subseteq S$. By definition, $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $x\in A\implies x\in B$ for all objects $x$. So this should mean that the inclusion “$\subseteq$” is not defined if either $A$ or $B$ is not a set. To see this, set $A=1$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$. Clearly, $A\in B$. But is it true that $\color{red}{x\in 1}\implies x\in\{1,2,3\}$? No, as there is no reasonable way to define the sentence $x\in 1$! Moreover, it is possible that $A\subseteq B$ but $B\notin A$ (e.g. take $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$).

Answer (score 0):

By the vanishing property, since $A=B$, $S=\{A\}=\{B\}$, hence $|S|=1$.

Comment: Ok, but how does it relate to $\{A,B\}$?

Comment: The vanishing property (I feel like I’ve made up the name  in hindsight but anyway) says that repeated elements in a set don’t matter; ie $\{1,2,1\}=\{1,2\}$ or in your case $\{A,B\}=(\{A,A\}=\{B,B\})=\{A\}=\{B\}$ since $A=B$