# How should we define set on ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How should we define set in ZFC?? I have heard sets are defined axiomatically in ZFC.But I have no idea why it is necessary to take zfc axioms to define set.It would be highly appreciated if anybody kindly explains it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually I wanted to ask this question.But nobody did get me.

Comment: Thr downvoters are requested to answer the question please.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, $\{1,1\}$ is a set. It's just that it's a set with **one** element, and it's equal to the set $\{1\}$. There is no such thing as a set with two equal elements (i.e. two elements who are equal to each other).

Comment: Will anybody please naswer my question without downvoting it?

Comment: @mathislove As you can see, the question already has an answer on another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742105/definition-of-set

Comment: It is not same..please read my question carefully..that is different.

Comment: @mathislove Yeah but by now the question is so much different I have no idea what you are asking. I mean, how else would you define something **other** than by using axioms?

Comment: My question is why it felt necessary to define sets axiomatically .where did we get stuck in.

Comment: @mathislove I understand. And my question is what other kind of definitions (not based on axioms) are there?

Comment: Tge downvoters re requested to pleqsr answer this question for this downvote I cannot even ask a question now.

Comment: U did not get me..I don't know.probably there is none.but my qustion is the reason behind the formulation of Zfc