# Question about set theory and first order logic

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, philosophy, foundations

I was studying first order logic by a book and the author uses set theory to define some concepts like models, structures, etc. Everything fine here, but then i started to read about ZFC set theory and the author uses first order logic to prove some theorems. My question is if this is valid. Seems a little circular, we use set theory to study logic and logic to study set theory.

Comment: Another duplicate question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769262/how-to-define-set-theory-and-first-order-logic-without-circular-reference with some comments

Comment: I have voted to close as a duplicate because, at the current level of detail in the question, nothing new is likely to be generated that is not already in the previous ones. That is not to say this is a bad question - it is a natural question that many people have thought of and asked in various settings. If there is a more specific question about the perceived circularity of first-order logic and set theory (beyond he fact that they may appear circular), that could make an excellt non-duplicate post.

Comment: @Carl: You can actually edit the duplicate list and add more duplicates.

Comment: @Asaf: thanks, I didn't know that. Unfortunately in this case it won't let me add the other duplicate because the other one has no answers.