# Are there textbooks on logic where the references to set theory appear only after the construction of set theory?

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, book-recommendation

In textbooks on logic the authors usually use the notions of *set* and *map* immediately, long before the set theory is constructed. That is strange for me, and I want to ask if anybody can advise me a textbook on logic with a "linear structure", without these "circles in definitions"?

EDIT. This question is a reference request, so I hope, if I cross post it to MathOverflow,  this will not cause a duplication of efforts for people who plan to post answers. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251099/are-there-textbooks-on-logic-where-the-references-to-set-theory-appear-only-afte) is this question at MO.

Comment: Carl Mummert's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/202159/14366) is quite relevant.

Comment: It is not possible in an "absolute" sense: imagine writing a grammar to describe "how language works". Do you think that you can do it without using language in writing the book ?

Comment: But you can see Kenneth Kunen, [The Foundations of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ) (2009).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes, I am not against Carl Mummert's idea of "describing a preliminary set theory" for using it in propositional calculus and in predicate calculus before the "true set theory" will be constructed. Did anybody do this in a textbook?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, as I can see, Kenneth Kunen describes set theory without mentioning axioms of first order logics that he uses. In my opinion that is not good. Do there exist texts where set theory is constructed as a first order theory with specifying the axioms of the corresponding first-order logic? Actually, I don't see the problem: one can formulate the axioms of predicate calculus + axioms of set theory, then consider the corollaries, and only after that discuss what they call "semantics of logic"? What is wrong with this?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov there is a book called "lógica y teoría de conjuntos" written by Carlos Ivorra Castillo, which you can download [here](http://www.uv.es/ivorra/Libros/Logica.pdf) but it is in spanish.  That book is divided in three parts, the first one is all about first order logic, the second one is about the logic behind set theory and finally the third one is about set theory. Sadly I don't think there is an english version, but if you understand spanish you might find it useful

Comment: @Eliana, unfortunately, I don't speak Spanish. If there is something in English or French, I would appreciate very much!

Comment: Does Russell and Whitehead's Principia Mathematica count?  It sounds like you are looking for a completely formal account of mathematics.  On a more practical note, if your only problem with Kunen's book is that he doesn't define the axioms of first-order logic, you can find another account of that elsewhere.  There are proof theory texts which present FOL in a completely syntactic sense.

Comment: @JasonRute, I thought, Russell and Whitehead are not used now, that isn't true? Which texts on FOL do you mean?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov, you never specified your intended use.  Yes, Russell and Whitehead's book is never used in practice.  However, it was a very clear attempt to give this linear structure you have in mind.  For pedagogical purposes, it is difficult to present foundations from the ground up, and almost no (if any!) textbook does it.  There are formal treatments of mathematics on computers that are completely formal, but this is not suitable to "read" as a textbook.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov, if you are looking for a treatment of FOL with syntax and not semantics, then you could read the first section of these notes (http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/handbookI/ChapterI.pdf).  The semantics stuff comes later and can be skipped.  (I am sure there are books too, but I don't have a good source off hand.  The one I know of is still being written.)

Comment: For people interested in constructive foundations, here are some relevant links: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1808558, http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1895288. I should note that the question of whether LEM (law of excluded middle) holds is not clear to me beyond the arithmetical hierarchy, even granting the complete collection of the natural numbers, because the original intuition or justification for LEM only applies to assertions about reality (see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1888389).

Comment: @JasonRute, thank you, I am reading this.

Comment: @user21820, thank you too.