# Why can multiplication be done in any order?

Tags: arithmetic

I have proof of $ab=ba$ and $abc=acb=bac=cab=cba=bca$ when the terms are all positive. But what about when they are not positive? What about when any number of terms multiplied together? I can't understand why we can rearrange the terms in any way possible. In case of two numbers, I can think of it as area and in case of three I can think of it as volume. But when it exceeds past that it gets difficult. And area and volume only work for positive numbers. What about when the numbers are negative?

Comment: Multiplication is defined to be commutative sometimes, and sometimes not. It **massively** depends on the context! E.g., Do you work, and do $a,b,c$ live, in an abelian group, a commutative algebra, or otherwise?

Comment: I assume from the content that you're referring to "normal" multiplication on the real numbers, like $2\times\pi=\pi\times 2$ - hopefully the commutativity of multiplication for integers, positive or negative, makes sense for you from repeated addition - and hopefully it follows that it makes sense for rationals too. As in, $2\times -3=-3 + -3 = -6$ and $-3\times 2= -(2 + 2 + 2)$...

Comment: How we go from rationals to arbitrary real numbers like $\pi$ is a bit harder - it's all in the definition, in the [construction of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers), if you're interested

Comment: I meant for any real numbers

Comment: I mean why can I rearrange $abcd$ to $bcab$ or $cabd$ or something else?

Comment: First of all, multiplication is also *associative*: $(ab)c=a(bc)$. Then if you accept $(ab)c=a(bc)$ and $ab=ba$ using your geometric intuition, then it follows for any amount of numbers that the same properties hold: $abcd=(ab)(cd)=(cd)(ab)=c(da)b=c(ad)b=(ca)(db)=(ca)(bd)=\cdots$ you can keep rearranging however you wish, with however many elements as you wish

Comment: Once you know that multiplication is commutative and associative, the proof should be done by *mathematical induction* on the length of the expression that you are studying.

Comment: Integers, rational numbers, real numbers, can be [constructed from natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156264/building-the-integers-from-scratch-and-multiplying-negative-numbers). Operations thus inherit the properties they have with naturals.

Answer (score 1):

The body of your question appeals to geometric intuition about area and volume. The commutativity and associativity of multiplication has an interpretation in this intuitive setting. Namely, that the x, y, z axes do not have an inherent order.

When you build something like a cube or a square and compute its volume, you are imposing an order on the axes, but that choice was arbitrary.

That's one way of thinking about it.

Also, in [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra), you do consider signed volume (i.e. [the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant)) and in this setting permuting the axes flips signs exactly when the permutation is composed of [an odd number of swaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation).

---

For real numbers, the proof of commutativity or associativity is a direct consequence of the [real axioms](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ehart/m524/realprop.pdf). Alternatively, you can prove it for real numbers using concrete constructions like [Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) or [Cauchy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences). Basically there are two families of approaches to defining what a real number is. You can build a real number out of simpler concrete things ... or you can specify up front what rules the real numbers must follow.

With that out of the way, proving commutativity and associativity of multiplication **for natural numbers** is pretty straightforward.

As an example, let's prove commutativity of multiplication for natural numbers.

We will proceed using [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

First, for zero, $0*a = a*0$.

Let we want to show that, if $k*a = a*k$, then $(k+1)*a = a*(k+1)$.

First, by assumption $k*a = a*k$.

Thus, $k*a + a = a * k + a$ .

Thus, $k*a + 1*a = a*k + a*1$ .

Applying distributivity, we get $(k+1)*a = a * (k+1)$.