# Matrix raised to a matrix: $M^N$, is this possible? with $M,N\in M_n(\Bbb K).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, exponentiation

I was wondering if there is such a valid operation as raising a matrix to the power of a matrix, e.g. vaguely, if $M$ is a matrix, is
$$
M^N
$$
valid, or is there at least something similar?  Would it be the components of the matrix raised to each component of the matrix it's raised to, resulting in again, another matrix?

Thanks,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is possible to define the exponential
$$\exp(M) = \sum_{n \ge 0}^{\infty} \frac{M^n}{n!}$$

of any matrix using power series. Similarly, it is possible to define the logarithm
$$\log(I + M) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} M^n}{n}$$

when the above series converges (this is guaranteed for example if the largest singular value of $M$ is less than $1$). We can therefore define
$$M^N = \exp(N \log M)$$

by imitating the identity $a^b = e^{b \log a}$ for, say, positive reals, but this won't have good properties unless $N$ and $M$ commute, I think. It's better to consider the exponential and logarithm separately.

As I have discussed [elsewhere on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56663/is-there-a-natural-way-to-extend-repeated-exponentiation-beyond-integers/56710#56710), the fact that the ordinary exponential takes two inputs which are the same type is misleading. Most (but not all) "exponential-type" operations in mathematics take two inputs which are different types.

Comment: Actually $\log(M)$ can be defined whenever $M$ is invertible, but there are many possible values (there is a choice of branch of the logarithm for each eigenvalue of $M$).

Comment: @Robert: that is not so clear to me if $M$ has nontrivial Jordan blocks. Do you want $M$ to be diagonalizable?

Comment: More generally, the holomorphic functional calculus defines $f(M)$ for any bounded linear operator $M$ on a Banach space and any function $f$ analytic in a neighbourhood of $\sigma(M)$.

Comment: In the case of a $d \times d$ Jordan block for eigenvalue $\lambda$, $f(M)_{i,i+k} = f^{(k)}(\lambda)/k!$ for $1 \le i \le i+k \le d$.

Comment: @Robert: ah, I didn't get that you were using the functional calculus. I thought you were just taking a term-by-term logarithm of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Could you recommend some place to look for taking the log of a bounded linear operator, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See e.g. Rudin, "Functional Analysis", sections 10.21 to 10.30.

Comment: I think, defining $M^N = \exp(\log M\cdot N)$ is more natural.

Answer (score 11):

> **Please See first some quick explicit computations below:**

I think the situation for to $2\times 2$ is more comprehensible. In oder to have a glimpse for the general case as mentioned by **@Qiaochu Yuan**
We know that the complex plan $\Bbb C$,
$$\Bbb C= \{a+ib: a,b\in\Bbb R\} $$ is isomorphic (as a field) to the to fields

$$G_2(\Bbb R) =\left\{\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a &b\\ -b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right): a,b\in\Bbb R\right\}$$

where one  merely identify

$$ 1 \equiv  \left(\begin{matrix}  1& 0\\0&1 \end{matrix}\right)~~~\text{and}~~~~ i \equiv  \left(\begin{matrix}  0&-1\\1&0 \end{matrix}\right)$$

> Now notion of exponential makes senses for complex numbers up to branch cut of the logarithm. Namely is not surprising to write $$ z^w
> ~~\text{for}~~~z = a+ib, w =x+iy\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}.$$
> which from the identification above readily represent the expression,
> $$ \color{blue}{z^w\equiv \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a &-b\\ b&a\end{smallmatrix}\right)^\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x &-y\\ y&x\end{smallmatrix}\right)~\text{for}~~~a,b, x, y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}}$$This expression is less abstract(but more particular and restricted) than, using the Taylor expansion for exponential and logarithm.

> **Another advantage of this expression is that, as opposed to the general cases where the expression of the $\log(M+I)$
> $$\log(I + M) = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} M^n}{n}$$
> converges only when $\|M\|< 1$, for the matrices taken in the fields $G_2(\Bbb R)$ such restriction is not required.**

**The above identification can be useful also to quickly compute the $n^{th}$ power of matrices([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526182/if-a-in-mathbbr-evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-left-beginsmallmatrix-1/2526194#2526194))**.

**Application 1:** Using the above identification we have,
$$ \displaystyle \left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 &-1\\ 1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)^\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 &-1\\ 1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)\equiv i^i = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\equiv \left(\begin{smallmatrix} e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}} &0\\ 0&e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\end{smallmatrix}\right) $$

**Application 2:** See here: :[For each $a \in \mathbb{R}$ evaluate $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&\frac{a}{n}\\\frac{-a}{n}&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526182/if-a-in-mathbbr-evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-left-beginsmallmatrix-1/2526194#2526194)

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\begin{matrix} 1&\dfrac{a}{n}\\\dfrac{-a}{n}&1\end{matrix}\right)^{\left(\begin{smallmatrix} n &0\\ 0&n \end{smallmatrix}\right)} &\equiv \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\color{red}{\left(1-\dfrac{ai}{n}\right)^n}  \\&= \left(\begin{matrix} \cos a&\sin a\\-\sin a&\cos a\end{matrix}\right).\end{align}$$

**Application 3:**

$$ \displaystyle\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 &1\\ -1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)^\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 &-1\\ 1&0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)\equiv (1+i)^i =  \left(\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}\right)^i = (\sqrt{2})^ie^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\\\equiv \displaystyle\left(\begin{smallmatrix} e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos\log \sqrt{2} &e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin\log \sqrt{2}\\ -e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin\log \sqrt{2}&e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos\log \sqrt{2}&\end{smallmatrix}\right) $$

**Application4:** with help of **Application 3:** compute
$$ \displaystyle\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 &1\\ -1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)^\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 &1\\ -1&2 \end{smallmatrix}\right) $$

This last one is left as an exercise to make sure the OP and future readers understood the rule of computation going on.

Comment: Nicely thought out answer.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @DanielV     Actually I think this can enlarge to the class of Quaternion which is also a field of dimension 3 . but the situation is more complex .

Comment: As multiplying by $i$ rotates the complex plane counterclockwise by a quarter turn, it's more natural to associate $i$ with the quarter-counterclockwise-turn matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I think the OP asked about non-commuting matrices.

Comment: @Anixx where is that mentioned in the post?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, it is possible to rise any square matrix to the power of any other square matrix (even of different order).

I use the following Mathematica code for this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
$PrePrint =.; FormatValues@Matrix = {};
Hold[MakeBoxes[Matrix[a_], StandardForm] ^:= 
    Block[{Internal`$ConvertForms = {}}, 
     TemplateBox[{MakeBoxes[MatrixForm@a][[1, 1, 3]]}, "Matrix", 
      DisplayFunction -> (RowBox@{style@"(", "\[NoBreak]", #, 
           "\[NoBreak]", style@")"} &)]]] /. 
  style[string_] -> StyleBox[string, FontColor -> Red] // ReleaseHold
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_?NumberQ, y_] := x y;
Dot[A_?SquareMatrixQ, B_?SquareMatrixQ] := 
  Matrix[KroneckerProduct[A, 
      IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
     KroneckerProduct[B, 
      IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]] /; 
   Length[A] != Length[B];
Protect[Dot];
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0, 0] = 1;
Protect[Power];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_?MatrixQ] := 
  First[First[x]] /; x == First[First[x]] IdentityMatrix[Length[x]];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_] := 
  Dot[Matrix[x], y];
Matrix /: NonCommutativeMultiply[y_, Matrix[x_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Dot[y, Matrix[x]];
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[x_], Matrix[y_]] := Matrix[x . y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_] + Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ + Matrix[y_] := 
  Matrix[x IdentityMatrix[Length[y]] + y];
Matrix /: x_?NumericQ Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x y];
Matrix /: Matrix[x_]*Matrix[y_] := Matrix[x . y] /; x . y == y . x;
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], y_?NumericQ] := 
  Matrix[MatrixPower[x, y]];
Matrix /: Power[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
  Exp[Log[Matrix[x]] . Matrix[y]];
Matrix /: Log[Matrix[x_?MatrixQ], Matrix[y_?MatrixQ]] := 
 Log[Matrix[x]]^-1 . Log[Matrix[y]]
Matrix /: Dot[Matrix[A_?SquareMatrixQ], Matrix[B_?SquareMatrixQ]] := 
 Matrix[KroneckerProduct[A, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
   KroneckerProduct[B, 
    IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]]

$Post2 = 
  FullSimplify[# /. 
     f_[args1___?NumericQ, Matrix[mat_], args2___?NumericQ] :> 
      Matrix[MatrixFunction[f[args1, #, args2] &, mat]]] &;
$Post = Nest[$Post2, #, 3] /. Dot -> NonCommutativeMultiply &;
```

Now one can use something like this:

```
Matrix[ {
    {0, 1},
    {1, 0}
   } ] ^ Matrix[ {
    {0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0}
   } ]
```

And get the result. Note though, the computation takes long time and the result may be huge in volume and include `Root` objects.