# Matrix to Matrix Power

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

Considering $A^b$, we have a nice definition and properties when $A$ is a matrix and $b$ is a real (or field) value.

We also have a fairly useful definition for $e^B$, where $B$ is a matrix and $e$ is the Naperian base.  I imagine this can be extended to an arbitrary base using logarithms.

My question is whether there is a general definition for $A^B$ with $A$ and $B$ as matrices with some suitable properties.  Some properties might be:

- $A^b$ and $e^B$ are special cases of the definition of $A^B$
- $A^I = A$
- $A^{B + C} = A^BA^C \text{ under suitable conditions }$
- $(A^B)^C = A^{BC} \text{ under suitable conditions }$

Is any such definition known?  Can computations be done with it?  What properties do we get and under what conditions?  Thank you, this is for my own curiosity.

---

Edit : Fly by Night found this previous question: [Matrix raised to a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164422/matrix-raised-to-a-matrix), but it doesn't really address the properties that I was asking about.  The real usefulness in a definition is in what you can infer from it, so I want to keep this question open.

Comment: you may like to see the new answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164422/matrix-raised-to-a-matrix/2527450#2527450

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is "nice enough" (being diagonalizable with strictly positive eigenvalues should do the job), you can define the logarithm of $A$ by the power series:
$$\log A = \log(1+(A-1)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(A-1)^n$$
Then you have $A=\exp(\log A)$ and thus:
$$A^B=\exp(B\log A)$$
(under suitable conditions).

Comment: This does not add to the answer given to the original duplicated question. See above comments to OP.