# How to find matrix exponential $e^A$

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential, cauchy-problem

I have the matrix $$A =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ - 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and I have to find $e^A$

I've found two complex-conjugate eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm i$

so substracting $\lambda_1 = i$ from the matrix's diagonal I got:

$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -i & 1 \\-1 & i \end{pmatrix}$$

and therefore. to find eigenvector I have to solve the system:

$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -i & 1 \\-1 & i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

so the first eigenvector is $h_1 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ i\end{pmatrix}$
 and the second one is $h_2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -i\end{pmatrix}$

so the general solution is $$x(t) = C_1e^{it}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\i\end{pmatrix} + C_2e^{-it}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\-i\end{pmatrix}$$

I know that now I have to solve two Cauchy's problems for the standard basis $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vectors $v_1 = (1, 0)$ and $v_2 = (0,1)$ But I do not know how to approach it for complex numbers

Comment: recommend taking more general $$B =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ - x & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and carefully writing out the four entries in $$ I + B + \frac{B^2}{2} + \frac{B^3}{6} + \frac{B^4}{24} + \frac{B^5}{120} $$ and see if the entries remind you of anything

Comment: To add to Will Jagy's hint, $A^2=-I$.

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix have real coefficients then it complex eigenvalues comes paired, that is, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then it is also $\bar\lambda$. For a $2\times 2$ matrix this mean that exists some change of basis $S$ such that $SAS^{-1}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&-\beta\\\beta&\alpha\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, where $\lambda=\alpha+i\beta$.

Then it can be shown that the matrices $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&0\\0&\alpha\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $C=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-\beta\\\beta&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ commute, then, from the definition of the exponential map, it can be checked that

$$e^A=S^{-1}e^{SAS^{-1}}S=S^{-1}e^{B+C}S=S^{-1}e^{\alpha I}\cdot e^CS=e^\alpha S^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\beta&-\sin\beta\\\sin\beta&\cos\beta\end{bmatrix}S$$

---

This result can be extended to find what is called the **extended normal Jordan form** of any real-valued matrix, what make easy the computation of it exponential. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices).

---

ADDITION: in the simple case that $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ we can use directly the definition of the exponential map noticing that $A^2=-I$, $A^3=-A$, $A^4=I$ and $A^5=A$. Thus

$$\begin{align}e^A:&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{A^k}{k!}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{I}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{A}{(2k+1)!}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac1{(2k)!}&0\\0&\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac1{(2k)!}\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac1{(2k+1)!}\\\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{-1}{(2k+1)!}&0\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos 1&0\\0&\cos 1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&\sin 1\\\sin(-1)&0\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos 1&\sin 1\\-\sin 1&\cos 1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Comment: Performing a complete Jordan decomposition is unnecessary in the general case. If the eigenvalues are $\alpha\pm i\beta$, then the traceless matrix $B=A-\alpha\,I$ satisfies $B^2=-\beta^2I$, so decomposing $A$ as $\alpha I+B$ allows a simple direct computation of $e^{tA}$.

Comment: @amd but $\alpha I+B$ is an extended Jordan matrix...

Comment: $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}0&-2\\1&2\end{bmatrix}}$, for instance, is not an extended Jordan matrix, nor is the corresponding $B=\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}−1&-2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}}$. My point is that this decomposition allows a straightforward calculation of the exponential of such a matrix without having to first find the change-of-basis matrix $S$. In particular, a similar computation to the one you have above gives $\exp(tB)=\cos\beta t\,I+[(\sin \beta t)/\beta]\,B$ and $\exp(tA)=\exp(\alpha t)\exp(tB)$.

Comment: @amd oh, I see. Thank you for the explanation, I was not getting the point of your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let$$T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\i&-i\end{pmatrix};$$its columns are the eigenvectors that you found. Then$$T^{-1}.A.T=\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}.$$Therefore,$$T^{-1}.A^n.T=\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}i^n&0\\0&(-i)^n\end{pmatrix}$$and so$$T^{-1}.e^A.T=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\begin{pmatrix}i^n&0\\0&(-i)^n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^i&0\\0&e^{-i}\end{pmatrix}.$$Therefore,\begin{align}e^A&=T.\begin{pmatrix}e^i&0\\0&e^{-i}\end{pmatrix}.T^{-1}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{e^i+e^{-i}}2&\frac{e^i-e^{-i}}{2i}\\-\frac{e^i-e^{-i}}{2i}&\frac{e^i+e^{-i}}2\end{pmatrix}\\&=\begin{pmatrix}\cos 1&\sin 1\\-\sin1&\cos1\end{pmatrix}.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

Let a,b $\in \mathbb{R}$ and
$$
\begin{align}
I &= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \\
J &= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0  & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Then the following formula is true,

> $$  \exp(aI + bJ) = \exp(a)[I \cos(b) + J \sin(b)]$$

In the special case where a = 0 and b = 1,

> $$  \exp(J) = 
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     \cos(1)  & \sin(1) \\
>     -\sin(1) & \cos(1) \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$

---

**Proof**

We will need the following lemmas to go through the chain of equalities. The lemmas are not going to be proved or explained here.

Let n $\in \mathbb{N}$, x $\in \mathbb{R}$, A and B two matrices

1. The product of $aI$ and $bJ$ is commutative
2. $\exp(A + B) = \exp(A)\exp(B)$ if $AB = BA$
3. $J^{2n} = (-1)^n I$
4. $J^{2n+1} = (-1)^n J$

Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
\exp(aI + bJ)
&= \exp(aI)\exp(bJ) \\
&= \exp(a)[I + bJ + (bJ)^2/2! + (bJ)^3/3! + \cdots] \\
&= \exp(a)[I(1 - b^2/2! + b^4/4! - \cdots) + J(b - b^3/3! + b^5/5! - \cdots)]  \\
&= \exp(a)[I\cos(b) + J \sin(b)]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Like here [For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ evaluate $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&\frac{a}{n}\\\frac{-a}{n}&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{n}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526182/for-any-a-in-mathbbr-evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-beginsma/2526194#2526194) Employing the Identification  $$ 1 \equiv  \left(\begin{matrix}  1& 0\\0&1 \end{matrix}\right)~~~\text{and}~~~~ i \equiv  \left(\begin{matrix}  0& 1\\-1&0 \end{matrix}\right)=A.$$

we get, $$\color{red}{A^n = i^n ~~~and~~~~ e^A =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{i^n}{n!} = e^i = \cos 1+i \sin 1 = \begin{pmatrix}\cos 1&\sin 1\\-\sin1&\cos1\end{pmatrix}.}$$