# Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, Prove $\det\begin{pmatrix} A & -B\\ B & A \end{pmatrix}=|\det(A+iB)|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, determinant

Let $A,B\in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb{R})$, Prove $\det\begin{pmatrix}
A & -B\\
B &  A
\end{pmatrix}=\bigg|\det(A+iB)\bigg|^2$

**My work:**

We know:

> $$|\det(A+iB)|^2=\sqrt{(\det(A+iB))^2}^2=\det(A+iB)^2=\det(A+iB)\det(A+iB)=\det((A+iB)(A+iB))=\det(A^2+AiB+iBA+i^2B^2)=\det(A^2+AiB+iBA-B^2)$$

Here I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Let $A, B$ be 1x1 matrices. Then the left hand side is $A^2 + B^2$, while the right hand side is $(A+iB)^2$, which is not equal to left hand side.

Comment: @xyzzyz: It's $|\det|^2$, not $\det^2$ itself.

Comment: it makes no difference to my counterexample. it's probably rather what @Guy Fsone says.

Comment: I think there is no need to have de module on the right hand side

Comment: @GuyFsone: The right side isn't even real without the absolute value.

Comment: @xyzzyz: It's fine in the $1\times 1$ case: $\det \pmatrix{s & -t \\ t& s} = s^2 + t^2 = |s + i t|^2$.

Comment: In higher dimension A and B must commute we need additional assumptions

Comment: You don't need $A$ and $B$ to commute. For $V = \mathbb{R}^n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$, consider the action of $Z + A + iB\in M_n(V)$ on the complex vector space $V\otimes \mathbb{C}$ and the real vector space $V \oplus i \mathbb{V}$. Use the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\phi(a + ib) = \pmatrix{a & -b \\ b & a}$ with $\det \phi(z) = |z|^2$.

Answer (score -1):

This follows directly from taking determinants of both sides of  the following identity
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ i & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A & -B \\ B & A\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -i & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} A + iB & -B \\ 0 & A - iB\end{pmatrix}
$$
and noting $\det (A + iB) $ and $\det(A-iB)$ are conjugates.

Comment: That requires computing the determinant of the block matrix on the far right (which behaves as described, by the OP might not have proved that yet.)

Answer (score -2):

> **Answer:** For  A and B commuting then we have $$\color{red}{\det \left(\begin{matrix}  A& -B\\B&A \end{matrix}\right)= \bigg|\det(A+iB)\bigg|^2 }$$

Similarly like here [For every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ evaluate $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&\frac{a}{n}\\\frac{-a}{n}&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{n}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526182/for-any-a-in-mathbbr-evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left-beginsma)
 by putting ourselves in the complex plan where we identify

$$ 1 \equiv  \left(\begin{matrix}  1& 0\\0&1 \end{matrix}\right)~~~\text{and}~~~~ i \equiv  \left(\begin{matrix}  0& -1\\1&0 \end{matrix}\right)\implies M=\left(\begin{matrix}  A& -B\\B&A \end{matrix}\right)= A+iB$$
Now assume that $A$ is invertible (**The case where A is not invertible will follows by density argument** ): then [from this](http://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2012/10/14/determinant-of-block-matrices/)

If A and B commute we obtain

$$\det \left(\begin{matrix}  A& -B\\B&A \end{matrix}\right)=\det(A+BA^{-1}B)\det(A)= \det(A^2+BA^{-1}BA)=\det(A^2+B^2)$$

But we have, $$\color{red}{|A+iB|^2 =(A+iB)(A-iB)= A^2+B^2 }$$

And hence since $|z|^2=z\bar z$ we obtain , $$\det( A^2+B^2)=\det\left((A+iB)\cdot(A-iB)\right)=\det( A+iB)\cdot\det( A-iB) \\=\det( A+iB)\cdot\overline{\det( A+iB)}= \bigg|\det(A+iB)\bigg|^2$$

Comment: Why does $\det$ commute with the map you describe?

Comment: I don't understand your point of view for this proof... If can explain a little more i can be very grateful.

Comment: The exercise is fine don't have error.

Comment: Yes, you have reason, i think the book have missing an hypothesis.

Comment: Why a down vote

Comment: Why is it necessary for $A$ and $B$ to commute? Do you have a counterexample? It follows in general just from the abstract nonsense of the map $M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ induces on the action of $\mathbb{C}$ on itself by multiplication; the question is basically just showing that the determinant behaves as expected under a change of the ground field.

Comment: @anomaly if check Op question it even less clear what the right hand side mean. With commutativity I have something clear If you have any suggestion I am  opened

Comment: What do you mean? The right side is the determinant of the complex matrix $A + iB$. Its absolute value is a real number, as is the left-hand size of the equation.

Comment: @anomaly yes. And to guess the correct meaning have a look OP's attempt

Comment: The OP's work is wrong. The problem as originally written, presumably from a linear algebra textbook, is correct.

Comment: @anomaly ofcourse it is wrong and non sense . as I said you should guess but not believe instead

Comment: @anomaly so far you wont fine any counterexample to my formula

Comment: Well, the original formula is correct. There are certainly counterexamples (to the correct equation) where $A$ and $B$ don't commute; it holds for any $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @anomaly see the update it is true for commuting matrices

Comment: why down voting this answer? down voter explain