# Find all values of : $(2)^{i+1}=?$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all values of :
>
> $$(2)^{i+1}=?$$

My Try :

$$i+1=\large\sqrt2e^{\frac{i\pi}4}$$

$$(2)^{\large\sqrt2e^{\frac{i\pi}4}}=?$$

now what ?

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2^{i+1} = e^{ (i + 1) \ln 2} = e^{\ln 2} e^{i\ln 2} = 2(\cos (\ln 2) + i\sin (\ln 2)) $$

Answer (score 1):

$$
 2^{i + 1} = e^{\ln 2} e^{i\ln 2} = 2(\cos \ln 2 + i\sin \ln 2)$$

For more example of such computaion 
see my answer here.[Matrix raised to a matrix: $M^N$, is this possible? with $M,N\in M_n(\Bbb K).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164422/matrix-raised-to-a-matrix-mn-is-this-possible-with-m-n-in-m-n-bbb-k/2527450?noredirect=1#comment5220971_2527450)