# Homomorphism Between 2x2 matrices and the Reals

Tags: algebras, ring-homomorphism

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.

1. Let $\mathfrak{A}_\mathbb{R}$ be the real unital subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ generated by the matrix $A$. Prove that there are no nonzero homomorphisms $\varphi:\mathfrak{A}_\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
2. Let $\mathfrak{A}_\mathbb{C}$ be the complex unital subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ generated by $A$. Prove that there is at least one nonzero homomorphism $\rho:\mathfrak{A}_\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

I'd appreciate any suggestions/hints/insights!

Comment: What is $A^2{}$?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2527450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $A^2=-I$ and so $A$ behaves like $i \in \mathbb C$.

Solution for 1:

> $\varphi(A)^2=\varphi(A^2)=\varphi(-I)=-\varphi(I)=-1$ cannot happen in $\mathbb R$.

Solution for 2:

> The elements of $\mathfrak{A}_\mathbb{C}$ are of the form $aI+bA$ with $a,b \in \mathbb C$. Define $\varphi(aI+bA)=a+bi$.

Comment: Okay so for 2, I considered $\rho:\mathfrak{A}_\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathfrak{C}$ where $\rho(X)=a+bi$ ,where $X=\begin{bmatrix}
 a & b\\
 -b & a
 \end{bmatrix}$. I can show that $\rho$ is a homomorphism; that is, that $\rho$ is a linear transformation and that $\rho(XY)=\rho(X)\rho(Y)$. Now, if I take $a=0$ and $b=1$, then $X=A$ and $\rho(A)=i\in\mathbb{C}$; hence, $\rho$ is nonzero. Is that correct for 2? Also, I know it's probably trivial, but how do I go about showing 1?