# Finite field generator exponentiation properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

For a finite integer field $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with a generator $g$ and $x\in\mathbb{Z}_n$, a property I do not understand arises and I have not come across an explanation for it. If another set of values $x_1=n+x,\ x_2=2n+x\dots$ then $g^{x}\neq g^{x_1}\neq g^{x_2}\dots$. Why is this? I've noticed and conjectured that for an $x_k=kn+x$, $g^{x}=g^{x_k +k}$ at least for several examples I have been toying with to get a feel for the mechanics. Since all these values are members of the same congruence class, I'd expect them to generate identical field elements. Is it because the multiplicative subgroup is of order $n-1 $ due to the removal of the additive identity? I'd appreciate any guidance and clarification on this matter.

Comment: Is $n$ a prime number?

Comment: Every element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ satisfies $g^p = g$, so $g^{2p} = g^2, g^{3p} = g^3$, etc. In other words, since the multiplicative group has order $p - 1$, the exponents are numbers that make sense $\bmod (p - 1)$, not $\bmod p$. In general exponentiation takes in two different types of objects as input; the fact that exponentiation seems like it takes in the same types of objects as input over the real numbers is misleading.

Comment: @Bernard yes it's a prime modulus, sorry for not including that detail explicitly.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, could you elaborate on the meaning of the phrase "exponentiation takes in two different types of objects..." please?

Comment: I have a long rant about this; I wrote a (bad) version of it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56663/is-there-a-natural-way-to-extend-repeated-exponentiation-beyond-integers

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  you’re right that is a long rant, but I rather like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your $n$ is a prime number, by *lil' Fermat*, we have $g^n\equiv g\mod n$, hence
$$g^{x_k}=g^{x+k}\enspace\forall k\in\mathbf Z.$$

Comment: Ah, so straight-forward. I just didn't make the connection. Thank you! Between your answer and Qiaochu Yuan's comments it is clear to me now.